# Using SqlBulkCopy with 2 Different Connection Strings

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an application that gets information from one server (server config stuff) and puts it into a centralized database on another server. There are several servers that I loop over from a text file.  I'm writing this application to eliminate the need for linked servers.

I'm trying to use SqlBulkCopy for copying the data but I'm running into problems.  I have been successful using SqlBulkCopy with a single SQL connection but when I try to use 2 different SQL connections I run into problems. The data never reaches its destination database. I have debugged through the code and can see that it reaches the try/catch but it appears that the command bulkcopy.WriteToServer(reader) it doesn't actually write any data to SQL.

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server= <ThatServer>; integrated security=true"
Dim connectionString2 As String = "Server= <MyServer>; Initial Catalog = <CentralizedDatabase>; integrated security=true"

    Using sourceConnection As SqlConnection = _
        New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        sourceConnection.Open()

        Dim commandSourceData As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("<mySQLcommand>", sourceConnection)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader

        Using sourceConnection2 As SqlConnection = _
            New SqlConnection(connectionString2)
            sourceConnection2.Open()
            Using destinationConnection As SqlConnection = _
                New SqlConnection(connectionString2)

                Using bulkcopy As SqlBulkCopy = _
                    New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = _
                        "<MyTableName>"

                    Try
                        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(reader)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                    Finally
                        reader.Close()
                    End Try

                End Using
            End Using
            sourceConnection2.Close()
        End Using
      sourceConnection.Close()
    End Using
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

**Solved.  Here's my code that works:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server = <ThatServer>; Initial Catalog = <sourceDB>; integrated security = true"
Dim connectionString2 As String = "Server= <MyServer>; Initial Catalog = <destinationDB>; integrated security=true"

    Using sourceConnection As SqlConnection = _
        New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim commandSourceData As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(<TSQL>, sourceConnection)

        sourceConnection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()

        Using destinationConnection As SqlConnection = _
            New SqlConnection(connectionString2)
            destinationConnection.Open()
            Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = _
                New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn1", "DestinationColumn1")
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn2", "DestinationColumn2")
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn3", "DestinationColumn3")
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn4", "DestinationColumn4")
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn5", "DestinationColumn5")
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn6", "DestinationColumn6")
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceColumn7", "DestinationColumn7")
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "<destinationTable>"
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader)
            End Using
            destinationConnection.Close()
        End Using
        reader.Close()
        sourceConnection.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: You didn't mention what problems you are having.  Do you have the source database specified in you actual connection string or select query?

Comment: Edited, thank you. I have the source database specified in my SELECT query by saying, "USE <myDB>"

Comment: So, what did you do to fix it?  What was wrong with the original?

Comment: I added column mappings.  That seemed to do the trick.